# Assigning a physical disk to a VMWare Guest OS in VMWare Server 2.0.2

Tags: debian, hard-drive, vmware-server

We recently migrated several servers to a single debian server running multiple virtual (also debian) servers on top of VMWare Server 2.0.2. One of the migrated servers is a fileserver that shares a large disk over the network via Samba. Problem is that the large disk can only be accessed by the Host OS.

We tried several possibilities to grant access to the disk to the guest OS, but nothing really worked. Using Samba or NFS resulted in slow disk access or limited control over file permissions, and creating a huge virtual disk image on the physical disk seems pretty pointless.

Is there a simple way to give the guest OS access to the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt that VMserver supports RDM.

Comment: That's correct according to https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Virtual_disk_image#Raw_disk_mapping